# cakephp open new window or sliding window

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am having a little trouble with understanding how to open a new window from an html link in a table view that is being queried in cakephp. I am using an html link inside the table to query the db. The link is displayed as a button using css. The results are then display in the browser, however I would like to have the data displayed in a new window or even a sliding window. Below is a sample of the code I am using. Your assistance is greatly appreciated as I have tried numerous solution with no results, Thanks

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<tr>
<td class="actions">
<?php echo $this->html->link(__('IDs'), array('action' => 'view', $user['User']['id']));?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open links in a new window using target="_blank":

```
<?php
    echo $this->html->link(
        __('IDs'),
        array('action' => 'view', $user['User']['id']),
        array('target' => '_blank')
    );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick. I tried something similar,but I was missing the "target" command as I was using window.open.